# Don't target child model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I'm trying to make a queryset of `Post` excluding `AdvertisePost`.

Here's my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...

class AdvertisePost(Post):
   ...
```

My current queryest: `posts = Post.objects.all()` targets both models. However I only want to target the `Post` model, not `AdvertisePost` - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
adv_posts_ids = AdvertisePosts.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
Post.objects.exclude(id__in=adv_posts_ids)
```

This is the equivalent of a SQL "not in" query

Hope that's what you are looking for :)